# How to best present data that is incomplete?

Tags: web-app, information

The app uses data and images to create an interface. It will be a web or native app.
Some of the data that is gathered is incomplete. Sometimes the data on the images are missed.

The question is: How do you represent that data in order to minimize or hide the fact that the data is not 100% complete.

Comment: The question is a little confusing, and I am not sure if english is your second language or not but let me help you fix it.

You have an app that has data on images and some of that data is not always 100%. Your question is: How do you represent that data in order to minimize or hide the fact that the data is not 100% complete. 

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, english is my second language. your statement are more clear than what i mean.

Comment: I was thinking deleting all those missed data might be a way to sort this but could also be lazy and is not responsible

Comment: What kind of data is it?

Comment: @ Jørn E. Angeltveit，yes, by how? sorry, i dont know.

Comment: @Vitaly Mijiritsky， like many items informations to supplement each image. The maker, the year, the description etc and above 20 items

Comment: @ Vitaly Mijiritsky， ohh, okay, did't notice that for this meaning before. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just show the data that are present.  Don't show the labels for the missing information until the user enters edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to represent the data would be to discard bad data and keep a percentage.

For example the dashboard could read something like: "6,233 image uploads (96% accuracy)" or it could be "6,233 image uploads (4% missed)"